# Fetching facebook pages using koala gem is not returning pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I am using graph api and koala gem to retrieve the pages of user and omniauth:facebook  gem to retrieve token of user and store it in session[:token]

If I access page using get_object(page_name) it shows all the data related to page,but when I try to fetch pages using get_connections() it was returning null(0).

```
def current_graph
    @current_graph ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:token])
end

pages = current_graph.get_connections('me', "accounts")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Facebook api version `2.4` and this work for me `@current_graph.get_object("#{id}/accounts")` where `id` indicate user facebook graph id. You can test it on [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/)

Answer (score 0):

Above code returning null array is because of facebook privacy policy.By default facebook only provides two permission public profile and email id.So if you want to access users pages and want to publish on users pages you have to get permission from facebook to MANAGE_PAGES and PUBLISH_PAGES.My application don't have permission hence it was returning null array.
Thanks For response.